# The pull and sync icons on Visual Studio 2022 are not clickable

Tags: .net, visual-studio, pull-request, visual-studio-2022

I **cannot pull** from a **certain branch** in my team web-app project.

Both the **pull and sync buttons** are not highlighting and unclickable on my **Visual Studio 2022**.

I have tried making some changes in the Tools > **Environment and Team explorer** settings, however they are not forthcoming.

Any suggestions?

Screenshot of the issue

[image: 1]

Comment: This would only happen if you are not at the root of your repo.

Comment: You don't have a remote branch yet. There's nothing to pull/sync from. Once you've pushed for the first time, they'll become available.